# hibernate functional coding

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following scenario where `authenticateUser()` calls `saveApplicationLog()`.

```
private boolean authenticateUser(String username, String password) {

    Session session = GCCPersistenceMangerFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Boolean found = false;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String query = "FROM PersistentUserMasterData where userName = '" + username+"',password = '"+password+"'"; 
        Query q = session.createQuery(query);
        List <PersistentUserMasterData> userInfo = new ArrayList<PersistentUserMasterData> (q.list()); 
        if (userInfo != null ) {
            for(PersistentUserMasterData user : userInfo) {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }finally {
        session.close(); 
    }

    if(found){
        ApplicationLogsDTO logsDto = new ApplicationLogsDTO(
                "Login was succesfull for LDAP user: "+ username,
                "LDAP_LOGIN_SUCCESS", "LOGIN", username, Severity.INFO.ordinal());

        saveApplicationLog(logsDto);//function 2
    }
    return found; 
}
```

//

```
public void saveApplicationLog(ApplicationLogsDTO log){

    PersistentApplicationLogs pLog = new PersistentApplicationLogs(
            log.getDetailDescription(), log.getEvent(), log.getEventSource(),log.getUser(), log.getSeverity(),getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr());
    Session session = GCCPersistenceMangerFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(pLog);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close(); 
    }

}
```

I want to make the whole operation atomic but don't want to merge these two functions, cause `saveApplicationLog()` is used by other functions too. What is right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you manage transaction with in methods then you can not do whole operation atomic.
you must move transaction management code to another method say `execute()` and call `authenticateUser()`  and `saveApplicationLog()`  from `execute()`. you have to use same session for both operations.

Comment: If I pass session of `authenticateUser()` to `saveApplicationLog()` will it work.

Comment: Yes, that will work given your transaction management code is only in authenticateUser()